# Resolution problem in C# .NET Winform application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, resolution

I have developed my winform application without caring about the resolution. Now am stuck up on PCs with a lower resolution. What to do now? Is there any way of conversion? I mean can the application get the resolution of the PC on which it is running, and set itself accordingly? Is there not any code or variable of Resolution in Windows which can be used ?

Comment: Do you refer to the pixel dimensions of the screen or the font scaling that the user has set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If want true resolution independence then you should develop using Windows Presentation Framework.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the resolution using [`VirtualScreen.Size`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.virtualscreen.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Hard to advice something... When you created your forms you should take care about smaller screens: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/manage-winform-controls-using-the-anchor-and-dock-properties/6165908

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
 Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Size;
```

and play with control anchoring. This is how I did it.
Problem also discussed: [fit windows form to any screen resolution](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformsdesigner/thread/6753e124-70c1-4e3a-b8f7-f4c076837627)

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of solutions for the problem given but most are based around the fact that you can build them into you're application from the start.

Simply manually changing the layout of you're application might be the 'fastest' way to go.

Getting 10 users to use a higher resolution might cost 10 * 100 dollar changing the application might costs 40 hours depending on application size.